# interrupting lua interpretation without ctrl -c quitting

Tags: lua, interpreter, break, interruption

I am running code from the book programming in Lua... http://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html

when I run this code in the terminal interpreter...   it continues reading input forever...

```
list = nil
    for line in io.lines() do
      list = {next=list, value=line}
end
```

Ctrl C returns me to the prompt/bash. Is there another command to break? How do I break/return from a chunk of lua code without exiting the interpreter?

Comment: Sorry for the Delay in saying thanks my brother broke my computer monitor. Ctrl D was the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

By pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> in a Unix-like system, you are sending your process the signal of `SIGINT`, which by default will terminate the process.

Your program continues reading from input forever because it's blocking in the call of `io.lines()`, which keeps reading from standard input. To interrupt it, send your terminal an `EOF`, this is done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> in a Unix-like system.

On Windows, the key to send `EOF` is <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. Ctrl+D is what I was looking for. In Linux the Ctrl+Z returns to the prompt > ^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 lua

Comment: Back to this can you help me create a shellscript or virus or deamon that will spam ctrl+C to SIGINT preventing any programs from running in terminal without explicit permission or disabling of this type of virus protection. I am not trying to kill the current program or break from it but do that to other terminal programs.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. PS i tried explaining the idea at tiny.cc/dfvp and github.com/punkroku/dfvp

Answer (score 3):

You can indicate the end of input for stdin by using either <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>.

Comment: Have you heard of autokey I want to use it with linux and spam ctrl C to prevent viruses. Or better if a terminal app runs then hold CTRL C or send pausebreak to keyboard buffer

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL-U` deletes all the characters before the cursor position, therefore the whole line. It also works like this in a Linux shell.